# Vscode always executes the code in the base environment first and then in the activation environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Vscode always executes the code in the base environment first and then activate my environment, can't it just activate my environment first then run the code? (Here I hide my user name)

```
C:\Users\<User-name>\Desktop\World\code>python -u "c:\Users\<User-name>\Desktop\World\code\ML Code\test.py"
3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
C:\Users\<User-name>\Anaconda3\python.exe

C:\Users\<User-name>\Desktop\World\code>C:\Users\<User-name>\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate C:\Users\<User-name>\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch

(pytorch) C:\Users\<User-name>\Desktop\World\code>
```

Here is my code:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)
```

And my settings:

```
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\<User-name>\\Anaconda3\\envs\\pytorch\\python.exe",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\<User-name>\\Anaconda3\\envs\\pytorch\\python.exe",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
```

Comment: just a roundabout solution, but you can always ditch VS code and try Pycharm for example. In Pycharm terminal it uses the virtual env, if interpreter is set to the same.

Comment: Yes, I spent a lot of time on this problem yesterday, and I was a little reluctant to give up. Maybe I should use Pycharm, thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of `Code Runner`, but the developer of `Code Runner` has not fixed this problem.

Some people have submitted this feature request in 2019 but without any response. refer to [here](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/434)

It seems like you need to bear on this inconvenience for now.

Comment: or switch to Pycharm, which is really awesome :-)